# How much time would it take to go to Alpha Centauri through a wormhole?

Tags: interstellar-travel

After reading a question about going to Alpha Centauri through an Alcubierre Warp I just became curious about going through a wormhole. I think it would happen instantly as far as I know about wormholes. Is that right?

Comment: If you "know about wormholes", what else do you want to know?

Comment: Since you know about them @Warp you know that they are theoretical concepts based on relativity and there is no proof they exist?

Comment: Probably the almost same amount of time as normal space travel. If you imagine a one-dimensional being living on a line, but the line is actually a circle (2D) but looks like a line to him. The "wormhole" for him would be a straight line connecting two points on the circle. But on the universe's scale, Sol and Alpha Centauri are right beside each other anyway. OK the universe could be irregularly shaped rather than a circle, but it would be amazingly good luck if they just happened to be either side of a "spike" that would be needed for a major saving.

Answer (score 2):

Although well beyond the scope of this website, it is sometimes fun to speculate about space travel techniques that have been proposed mathematically but never proven.

An Einstein-Rosen Bridge (more commonly, a "wormhole") is not usually considered to be a zero-length connection between two points in space.  Rather, a common interpretation is of a projection of a (hypothesized and never yet observed) higher spatial dimension into our own 3-D universe.  This projection, having non-zero length, would require non-zero time to traverse.

As far as we know ([basically nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Faster-than-light_travel)), you'd travel through the wormhole at speeds governed by relativity.  So your travel time would depend on the length of the wormhole and your propulsion technology.  In short, it would be like travelling through normal space, except with the extra magic of wormholes.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Einstein-Rosen wormholes are not currently considered the most physically plausible form of wormhole.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm not a huge expert on hypothetical superluminal travel :-P